# Execute() is not returning a value

Tags: vimscript, ex-mode, echo

I am apparently not getting a return value from execute():

```
function! Example()
    return 5
endfunction

:echo execute("call Example()")
```

Just results in a blank line. The 5 is not printed. Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of `execute`, i.e. `:h execute()`:

> `execute({command} [, {silent}])`
>   Execute `{command}` and capture its output.
>   If `{command}` is a String, returns `{command}` output.
>   If `{command}` is a List, returns concatenated outputs.

`execute()` returns the output of whatever is executed, not the return value of any function that may (or may not) be executed.

As an example,

```
echo execute('echo "test"')
```

will echo "test", while

```
echo execute('call SomeFunc(...)')
```

will only output whatever is echoed inside the function `SomeFunc`. The return value is not relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

this is because `call Example()` alone wouldn't print anything.
You need `:echo execute("echo Example()")` for execute() to print anything.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to print the return value of the function, you don't need the `execute` or the `call`:

```
:echo Example()
```